# broadcastreceiver Some codes do not work

Tags: android

I have a problem when I send data to the app I only receive messages but I want to like changing the button shape and so on but it does not work

```
package com.pioneer.it.gcmpro;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class PushReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String title="P";
        String text="T";

        if(intent.getStringExtra("message")!=null)
            text=intent.getStringExtra("message");

        Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity
                (context,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);
        Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);

        b.setText("" + text);
        Toast.makeText(context, "" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    }
}
```

This line only works Toast.makeText(context, "" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

but this line not work b.setText("" + text);

why?

Answer (score 1):

You are never displaying your inflated layout. So you are inflating a layout into RAM, then set the text for a textbox but then you never display it anywhere. This is why you cannot see it.

Also, it is bad practice to directly inflate a layout in a `BroadcastReceiver`. If you want to display a view, please start an activity from your `onReceive`.

Comment: I did not understand you have a solution to the problem

Comment: See @meikiem's answer

Answer (score 0):

in this way you can not display your view,
you should start your activity and send your text as extra to it like this:

you have intent in onReceive so:

```
intent.putExtra(text, your_key);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

and in your MainActivity(I assumed that it is MainActivity from your layout name) get your Extra and set it like this:

```
Button yourButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
yourButton.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("your_key"));
```

Comment: but application kick me

Comment: told me there error is here context.startActivity(in);

Comment: do you give context to your receiver when you want to sendBroadCast?

Comment: do you have a better tutorial video

Comment: check the context you are giving when you are sending broadcast  :                                                   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).sendBroadcast(new Intent("your_intent_key"));

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inflating the layout here in Reciever, You can have activity or fragment, use that layout for that activity or fragment.

And initialize and create that button as public static in that Activity/Fragment.

When you receive the message ( onRecieve method called ), You can access that button from here(as it is public static) and you can update the UI of that button.